# Convert header and lib into a dll to use it with c#

Tags: c#, c++, header, lib

i'm trying to develop a software based on a lib and header c++ files given from another company. I don't know how the lib is built, i can only see the signature of the function inside the header.
Since i'm asked to make a GUI over this software i wanted to convert those file into a dll to import them inside a c# project.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Visual C++/CLR Class Library Project and use it as a bridge between C++ lib and C# project